# Prevent direct access to database

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm thinking on a way to secure a PHP application. I would like to set up a user with limited rights on the database server side (MySQL), and configure this user in the PHP application for all database requests.

Now the problem is that someone who could have access to the source files (for example an employee) can uses the configured credentials to directly connect to the database (for example via phpmyadmin). The database should be updated only through the PHP application.

I would like to set up a mechanism (trigger or whatever possible on mysql side or php side or both) which checks from which client a request to the database come from, thus ignoring it or not. Is it possible to do that? Are there others ways to consider this problem?

Regards

Comment: If you make sure that the user in question does not have any privileges that they wouldn't be able to use on the website itself, what is the issue if somebody gets the login info?

Comment: You can tie down access to, for example, SomeUser@localhost, and thereby prevent access from outside the server. However, if someone has legitimate access to PHPMyAdmin on the server then MySQL couldn't tell whether the access as SomeUser@localhost is legitimate or not.

Comment: @Evan The application has a config file, with the credentials to connect the database for CRUD (login, password). Someone can reads this file and uses the info to bypass the application and access the database. I would like to deny any modification in this case.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I understand. So What I'm thinking of is impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the problem is that someone who could have access to the source files (for example an employee) can uses the configured credentials to directly connect to the database (for example via phpmyadmin).

This isn't something you can fully prevent. If somebody has access to the source files, you are screwed no matter what.

What is usually done to create *some* protection is

- to configure mySQL in a way that it's not accessible from outside the server. See [Restricting MySQL connections from localhost to improve security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208614/restricting-mysql-connections-from-localhost-to-improve-security) and it should be done on Firewall level as well (talk to the sysadmin)
- have the web app use a database user account that is limited in access to whatever tables and features the app needs to function.

Comment: +1 Only caveat: it might happen that the employee has access to the source from (say) a Git repository, but still the password is environment specific, it's stored in a config file that is only in the server. In this scenario, the employee must have access to the live server, not just to the source

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the domain from which some user can login you can specify that when you grant that user priviledges:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yourdatabase.* TO 'username'@'192.168.10.12'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'goodsecret';

This would limit the connections to 192.168.10.12, even if the password would be provided from another location it wouldn't fit this grant command.