# Start mySQL Server out of a Ruby program

Tags: ruby

I have a Linux server where I start a few Ruby programs during the day. The server is directly connected to the internet (no firewall) at a hoster and I wonder, if there is a way to start and close the mySQL server just before I update the db and close it afterwards. The target is, to have the mySQL server only open when it is needed. So I thought it might be a way to activate the port or the service directly out of Ruby.

thank you for answering,

Werner

Comment: Why do you need that? If for security reasons, why don't you restrict mysql to localhost only?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208614/restricting-mysql-connections-from-localhost-to-improve-security

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to change the permissions to the database through ruby, then, doing whatever you want to do, and change the permissions back.

You could do that usig the mysql gem, connecting to the database and running the commands.

Then restart the process, and do the same thing but backwards

Honestly, I don't know why you would do that, and I wouldn't recommend someone to do that. But that would be my approach