# Allow access to phpmyadmin from localhost only

Tags: apache, localhost

I am trying to config my server phpmyadmin to access only from the localhost and not from the remote. Below is the configuration on server `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

```
 Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

 <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1

   Options FollowSymLinks
   DirectoryIndex index.php

</Directory>
```

So, while I access phpmyadmin from remote I am getting 403 forbidden which is good but when I access phpmyadmin from localhost (that is from server using remote desktop), I am still getting 403 while I think this should give access to phpmyadmin from localhost. Anything I am missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

#### Logical mistake

You make one big mistake, every one of you.

PhpMyAdmin **is NOT a server**, it's just a client written as a PHP script and served by some HTTP server (Apache in this case).

That what you want(ed) and others suggested doing is trying to disable access for `phpmyadmin` **vhost** of the HTTP server, but it will be still possible to log in into the base with **any** other client from terminal's `mysql` command, to GUI client like MySQL Workbench or IDE's build in DB clients. Where's the logic?

Of course, you can join both techniques (HTTP securing and MySQL securing) however without the second your database will be still unsafe. **PhpMyAdmin is just a client!** It has even own mechanics for controlling access, but if someone will use any other client (mentioned above) your effort will be absolutely worthless).

#### Solution:

To maintain your case you should create a dedicated MySQL account with `localhost` access (I can bed, that at the moment of writing this post it is/was `%` which means global), then MySQL will control all incoming connections to check if they are from local machine or from the world.

Just don't forget to remove the account with global access (`%`) and flush the privileges after all changes.

Also, I always suggest creating exactly one user with all privileges to exactly one dedicated database (ofc, other than `root`). That way, even if you are only admin who works at the many databases, you minimize the risk of accidental changes in other databases. (Pro-tip, good password manager will be your friendly ghost-guard).

I'd suggest googling it and get overall knowledge over this topic, as it's quite crucial for DB security, however that'll be also enough if you'll implement simple solution from very first answer found. Using `localhost` restriction on MySQL, preferably with setting blocking of `3306` port on the firewall side, is a perfect solution to access your data with locally installed PhpMyAdmin **script** 100%  securely(if that's possible at all).

Below cite answer from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208652/1066240)

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO db_user @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO db_user @'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
```

```bash
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

P.S. You dont need even to write SQL command for this, you can change it for each user with... PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are using Apache 2.4.x.  The syntax for access control changed between 2.2 and 2.4.  The `Order` and `Deny` syntax you're using is for Apache 2.2, but won't work for 2.4.  In 2.4 it would be something like:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

[Reference from Apache upgrade doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html), and [Access Control docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using Apache 2.4.18. I have made changes as per your above answer and restarted the apache. Still I am not able to access phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Don't use `Require ip 127.0.0.1`, it is not reliable. Use `Require local`

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana reference? Both the links I provided show using `Require ip`; the upgrade doc uses `Require ip 127.0.0.1`. Neither mention any unreliability.

Comment: @user254153 Does Apache work at all, eg `http://localhost/`?  How are you trying to access PHPMyAdmin? And, just to be sure, what does `Still I am not able to access` mean, exactly? What do the Apache logs show?

Comment: I mean I am still getting 403 forbidden error after mentioned changes.

Comment: @Don'tPanic you are right, lets wait until they check they're error_log. To check the error_log live, use `tail -f /path/to/apache2/error_log`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, and make it so that you can only access it locally, it should be something like this mostly, but :

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Require local
    #......otherthings (also, only copy the line Require local)
```

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the login to localhost for an admin user does not keep a user from login in from the outside if phpMyAdmin is on the same server as the database because the connection from the database to phpMyAdmin is a local connection.

See the link below:

[I'm able to login on phpMyAdmin with root, even it's restricted to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466877/im-able-to-login-on-phpmyadmin-with-root-even-its-restricted-to-localhost)

To be secure from brut force logins one can block remote access to phpMyAdmin and use a SSH tunnel to gain access from the outside if needed.